# IOS app - bluetooth audio enabling

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I'm working on an IOS 6 app that's currently in development. The app has about 5-6 snippets of audio that play at various stages, currently when the device is paired with some bluetooth speakers (e.g. in a car) the audio does not play through the speakers.

Does anyone know what's involved with making this app work with paired bluetooth speakers? My initial assumption was that it wouldn't need anything extra done, it would just work. I had thought bluetooth paired speakers worked like as if you'd plugged in speakers directly into the device, all audio was routed through the speakers as long as they were paired.

This doesn't appear to be the case though.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem as yours, did you find a solution to it? To automatically use the default audio output?

Comment: I'm afraid development on the app was stopped before a solution to this was found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place an [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) somewhere in your interface, and enable the showsRouteButton property, then users can use that button to change the audio route to Bluetooth. You can also disable the showsVolumeSlider property if you don't need the volume slider.